# MongoDB Ruby Driver - Create user w/out password

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Trying to use the following code to create a user that uses mongodb X509 authentication...

```
client = Mongo::Client.new(["#{Facter.value(:hostname)}:#{config['net']['port']}"],
                                      auth_mech: :mongodb_x509,
                                      ssl: true,
                                      ssl_cert: "#{config['net']['ssl']['PEMKeyFile']}",
                                      ssl_key: "#{config['net']['ssl']['PEMKeyFile']}",
                                      ssl_ca_cert: "#{config['net']['ssl']['CAFile']}",
                                      :database => '$external',
                                      :connect => 'direct')
client.use(:$external).database.users
          client.database.users.create(
          "CN=#{Facter.value(:nodetype)},OU=Mike",
          roles: [ Mongo::Auth::Roles::READ_WRITE_ANY_DATABASE ]
          )
```

When I catch the exception I get this...

> "pwd" had the wrong type. Expected string, found null (14)

In the mongodb documentation it states that when using the $external database to insert a user you do not need to specify the password.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-users/

I can accomplish this (adding user w/out pwd) using the mongo shell, but it seems the Ruby driver's Mongo::Database class method does not allow empty password fields.  Is there a different way to add a user in the Ruby driver for MongoDB that allows for nil password entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug with the MongoDB-Ruby driver.  Please refer to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-2055